# array_push for associative arrays

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array, array-push

I'm trying to extend an assoc array like this, but PHP doesn't like it.

I receive this message:

```
Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given
```

Here's my code:

```
$newArray = array();  
foreach ( $array as $key => $value ) { 
    $array[$key + ($value*100)] = $array[$key];
    unset ( $array[$key] );
    array_push ( $newArray [$key], $value );
}
//}
print_r($newArray);
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: oh ok, sorry. Will do next time. After all it's in my interests too! Thanks.

Comment: that code looks really messy, would you tell us what you're trying to do?

Comment: I had no luck with Ariz's method, I don't think it is correct.  It created the index but would not set the value.  See the answers below for the proper syntax of `$newArray[$key] = $value;`

Comment: i'm trying to use array push but for an assoc array not a numeric array

Comment: php has assoc arrays. It has not numeric arrays like they defined in other languages. So even if you set up an array with only values, you also have indexes to.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

This is your problem:

$newArray[$key] is null cause $newArray is an empty array and has not yet values.

You can replace your code, with

```
array_push( $newArray, $value );
```

or instead of array_push to use

```
$newArray[$key] = $value;
```

so you can keep the index of your $key.

Comment: Of course you are right! An assoc array doesn't rely on its numbering system so just adding another pair is the best way! Array push is more about giving the value a key. So it was a stupid question since assoc arrays already have a key!! Thanks for your time anyway!

Comment: The different is that `array_push()` always add an element to the bottom of an array while `$array[$key] = $value` may overwrite an element of your `$array`.

Answer (score 9):

I use array_merge prebuilt function for push in array as associative.

For example:-

```
$jsonDataArr=array('fname'=>'xyz','lname'=>'abc');
$pushArr=array("adm_no" => $adm_no,'date'=>$date);
$jsonDataArr = array_merge($jsonDataArr,$pushArr);
print_r($jsonDataArr);//Array ( [fname] => xyz [lname] => abc [adm_no] =>1234 [date] =>'2015-04-22')
```

Comment: Clever, Was looking for a way to push a mix of asssociative and incremental index into one single array and keep the order they've been 'pushed.